# Parsing date in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I am using SQL Server 2005.

My `Trade_Date` column is of datatype `datetime`.

It has values as: `2/12/2013 11:59:00 PM , 2/13/2013 11:59:00 PM`

i.e. different dates with time.

I want to compare date [only date] in where clause.

I am trying with following query:

```
select * 
from foclosing 
where CONVERT(varchar(11), Trade_Date) like '2/12/2013 %'
```

or

```
select * 
from foclosing 
where Trade_Date = CONVERT(datetime, '2/12/2013')
```

but both of these queries are not working.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Also see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from foclosing
where Trade_Date >= '20130212' AND Trade_Date < '20130213'
```

1. Use yyyymmdd which is safe for SQL Server
2. Don't apply functions to columns, then compare (your 1st query)
   See mistake 2 here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/
3. Don't compare locale-based dates as varchar (your 1st query)
4. Trade_Date has a time element which is why your 2nd query fails

In summary, a date conversion should not be used for examples like this: datetime is a range

Comment: Please also mention in your answer : :     SELECT * FROM foclosing WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Trade_Date, 111) = convert(datetime,'2/12/2013')

Comment: @Freelancer: this is a very bad pattern as per my 2nd bullet point

Comment: ohh..sorry, i thought that is also regular practice.